# show all users same countdown

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i am using javascript timer and i want all users to see the same countdown,example when the first user login on page timer is starting and all users after will see the same timer.
Asp net mvc 3.0

Comment: That's great. Now what's your question?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jquery countdown timer that you can sync with your server.  That is if I understood your question.  It could benefit from re-phrasing.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/countdown2